# Code validation

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, ethers.js, hardhat

Hi i want to deploy my first smart contract to the Eth mainnet and this require a lot of money and i am very scared can someone want to help me and validate this code for any errors becouse i cant run this on testnet becouse this i have error not asocieted with this contract the ethers cause this error and i dont know how to fix this can somone help me validate this code becouse i dont want to spend a lot of money on something which wont work.
This code take Equalizer finance flash loan and performs swaps on 2 dexes and repays the flash loan this code also have a withdraw function
I know that the compiler has found 2 errors but i think this is not a critical error and this flash loan requires this variable to work properly.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";

interface IERC3156FlashBorrower {
    function onFlashLoan(
        address initiator,
        address token,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 fee,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external returns (bytes32);
}

contract FlashBorrower2 is Context, ReentrancyGuard, IERC3156FlashBorrower {
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    address private owner;
    uint256 public constant MAX_INT = type(uint256).max;
    address USDC = 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier OnlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function onFlashLoan(
        address initiator,
        address token,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 fee,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external override OnlyOwner nonReentrant returns (bytes32) {
        IERC20(token).approve(msg.sender, MAX_INT);
        uint256 amountOutExpected;
        uint256 amountOutExpected2;
        (amountOutExpected, amountOutExpected2) = abi.decode(
            data,
            (uint256, uint256)
        );
        address UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
        address SUSHISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0xd9e1cE17f2641f24aE83637ab66a2cca9C378B9F;

        IUniswapV2Router02 uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(
            UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS
        );
        IUniswapV2Router02 sushiSwapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(
            SUSHISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS
        );

        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = token;
        path[1] = USDC;

        uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            amount,
            amountOutExpected,
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );

        address[] memory path2 = new address[](2);
        path2[0] = USDC;
        path2[1] = token;

        sushiSwapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            IERC20(USDC).balanceOf(address(this)),
            amountOutExpected2,
            path2,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );

        return keccak256("ERC3156FlashBorrower.onFlashLoan");
    }

    function withdrawWETH(address WETH) external OnlyOwner {
        require(
            IERC20(WETH).balanceOf(address(this)) > 0,
            "No funds to withdraw"
        );
        IERC20(WETH).transfer(owner, IERC20(WETH).balanceOf(address(this)));
    }
}
```

Comment: You have 5 warnings associated with it. But you can still deploy in testnet for testing. What's the problem you are facing while deploying in testnet?

Comment: i got 2 warnings and  all of this warning tells me this [{
 "resource": "/e:/SandwitchV1/contracts/SUSHI-V2.sol",
 "owner": "solidity-language-server",
 "code": "5667",
 "severity": 4,
 "message": "Unused function parameter. Remove or comment out the variable name to silence this warning.",
 "source": "solidity",
 "startLineNumber": 38,
 "startColumn": 9,
 "endLineNumber": 38,
 "endColumn": 26
}] and points that i dont use fee and iniatior variables but i think the equalizer finance require this variable becouse this function is taken from them

Comment: Can you point me this errors ?

Comment: Its just the warning that you are not making use of those parameters, you can still deploy and test in testnet. Try using https://remix.ethereum.org/ or hardhat

Comment: After few hours i succesfully debug error and i deployed this to testnet but i have error which i dont know from where come from Error: transaction failed [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (transactionHash="0x05b56cf7dde5495ec7ff5ed13bf1a64f45481e19c20fd948b69f56a0669e9a7d", transaction={"type":2,"chainId":11155111,"nonce":21,"maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x010aaeb4f1"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x010aaeb4f1"},"gasPrice":null,"gasLimit":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x017d7840"},"to":"0xD6011CC83d2Be6db63105574e230D8314307518e"

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using a testnet, you could use a tool like hardhat, truffle or even Remix with some plugins to test it locally. These tools allow you to deploy it on a local blockchain, write tests to check that everything works fine and even clone the blockchain of your choice, so that you can interact with already deployed contracts which seems to be your case.

This is the best way to be as sure as possible that everything works and that you did not miss any major errors.

I personally use hardhat, you can find their starter guide here: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/getting-started#quick-start
I never used Truffle but it is similar, and Remix is maybe more beginner friendly as it is web browser based, I encourage you to check them out.

Comment: This is the right answer. Foundry is my personal favorite for testing at the moment.